# Do i have to make up for my missed fasts by fasting for 5 years?

Tags: sawm

I didn't know that we cant drink water and eat when the fajr azan is being called.Meaning that we should eat our suhoor before the fajr azan

Now usually I used to drink water when the fajr azan is being called. I would stop of course after the azan finishes BUT

Still that means most of my fasts are invalid or are they?
And if they are should I make up for them ? ( even though I was ignorant of the matter?

Another Q&A site told that I should make up for my missed fasta but thata impossible since for each missed fast I should fast nonstop 60 days and I must have missed around 60 fasts . So 30×60 = 1800 days

So I should fast nonstop for 5 years ? :(

Answer (score -1):

For any fast you miss you just make up the day you missed not 60 days

Comment: Why? Elaborate! Read [answer].

Comment: This answer is entirely opinion based. Please provide facts and references that support your answer. Nonetheless, once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.